# how to insert data into multiple table using select query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

How can I `insert` the data into multiple tables using a `select query`?

```
INSERT INTO PermissionRole(code,isValid,longValue,shortValue),
INSERT INTO PermissionRole_authorisedFunctions 
VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),brfm.authorisedFunctionCode)
SELECT urt.code, urt.isValid, urt.longValue, urt.shortValue, brfm.authorisedFunctionCode 
FROM Ref_UserRoleType urt 
INNER JOIN ref_businessrolefunctionmap brfm
ON urt.code=brfm.businessRoleCode;
```

Comment: Since i don't have enough reputation to comment, i'm giving this in answer's section. This question already have an answer in stackoverlfow. check the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471757/insert-rows-into-multiple-tables-in-a-single-query-selecting-from-an-involved-t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT rows into multiple tables in a single query, selecting from an involved table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471757/insert-rows-into-multiple-tables-in-a-single-query-selecting-from-an-involved-t)

Comment: If you are not on mysql 8 or above the use of cte as explained in the links mentioned in the previous 2 comments (which was a potgresql question BTW) is not available to you. An insert can only insert to 1 table it may be worth your while looking at a trigger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql - Insert values into multiple tables with unknown primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486670/mysql-insert-values-into-multiple-tables-with-unknown-primary-key)